# NullPointerException when mocking controller class

Tags: java, unit-testing, nullpointerexception, jmockit

i wanted to write some tests for the method shown in the code below. I'm mocking dependencies with JMockit. For whatever reason i am getting a NullPointerException all the time and i really don't understand why that happens. I'm new to JMockit and in mocking dependencies in general. Stack Trace just shows NullPointerException thrown at line `new NonStrictExpectations()`
.

**Method to test**:

```
@Override
public boolean addSubject(User user, Schedule schedule, SchoolSubject subject) {
    final boolean result = schedule.addSubject(subject.getHourTime(), subject);
    scheduleDAO.update(schedule);
    if (subject.getTeacher() != null && !subject.getTeacher().trim().isEmpty()) {
        for (final TeacherEntry teacher : user.getTeachers()) {
            if (subject.getTeacher().equals(teacher.getName())) {
                teacher.getSubjects().add(subject.getName());
                teacherDAO.update(teacher);
            }
        }
    }
    try {
        userDAO.update(user);
    } catch (final DuplicateUniqueFieldException e) {
        throw new UnexpectedUniqueViolationException(e);
    }
}
```

**Test method:**

```
//imports not copied
public class ScheduleManagerTest {

@Tested
ScheduleManager manager;

@Injectable
UserDAO userDAO;

@Injectable
ScheduleDAO scheduleDAO;

@Injectable
TeacherEntryDAO teacherDAO;

@Injectable
SchoolSubjectDAO schoolSubjectDAO;

@Mocked
Schedule schedule;

@Mocked
SchoolSubject subject;

@Mocked
User user;

@Test
public void testAddSubject() throws DuplicateUsernameException, DuplicateEmailException {

    new NonStrictExpectations() {

        {
            schedule.addSubject(anyInt, (SchoolSubject) any);
            result = true;
            scheduleDAO.update((Schedule) any);
            subject.getTeacher();
            result = anyString;
            subject.getTeacher().trim().isEmpty();
            result = false;
            user.getTeachers();
            result = (ArrayList<TeacherEntry>) any;
            teacherDAO.update(((TeacherEntry) any));
            userDAO.update((User) any);
        };
    };

    assertTrue(manager.addSubject(user, schedule, subject));

    }
}
```

I think i'm doing something pretty wrong :(

Comment: Hmm... I see lots of mistakes and bad practices (easily counted a dozen of them) both in the production code (eg, use `final` consistently, don't return `boolean` unnecessarily) and in the test code (eg, don't use the "test" prefix for JUnit 4 tests, use `throws Exception` in test methods). So, my sugestion is to read programming books, study the language and its idioms, and perhaps not attempt to use advanced tools (a mocking library) until you get more knowledge and experience. May not be what you wanted to hear, but it's the most useful advice...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to know what is going wrong based on the description, but here's a guess:

Mocked objects will return null in their methods by default.  You'll get a null pointer here:

```
subject.getTeacher().trim()
```

because getTeacher() will return null.  To return a teacher, you'll have to either use a real subject or do further mocking with

```
Mockito.when(subject.getTeacher()).thenReturn(new Teacher());
```

Comment: sry for my bad description. i see that seems to be the problem. my test is not interrupted by the npe thank you. I got one question is it possible to mix jmockit and mockito?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `@RunWith(JMockit.class)` to your class

```
@RunWith(JMockit.class)
public class ScheduleManagerTest {

...
```

Comment: just tried it but this won't fix it. Aren't `@RunWith` annotations for integration tests? i want to test my class as a component alone, that is why i am trying to mock it's dependencies. :)

Comment: Make sure you are following the first three steps in this guide. http://jmockit.org/gettingStarted.html